# Is there potential for XSS when interpreting JSON strings to JavaScript objects in browsers?

Tags: json, xss

I'm producing Chart.js JavaScript code in a C#, and wondering at the potential for XSS.

I'm dumping the following JS code as part of a larger HTML string:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var c = JSON.parse('{"type":"bar","data":{"labels":[...]],"datasets":[{},{}, etc]},"options":{"scales":{"yAxes":[{},{}]}}');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, c);
```

Would it be possible to change the contents of `c` prior to the execution of `var myChart = new Chart(ctx, c)`?

Or, would it be possible to force that line to re-evaluate with a changed `c` variable? It would seem to me that it is at least theoretically possible to add an IIFE to the JSON, if you could re-assign it.

My use case is this:

1. User connected to VPN
2. User types in domain name, which returns a single HTML page
3. HTML page contains JavaScript to make requests to server on VPN C# server

So I've enabled CORS on the C# server for this particular domain.

I don't think there is the possibility of XSS without using an `eval` function from user input, but just want to make sure. This is new territory for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSS happens when user-provided (or attacker-provided) code is executed on your page.

If can certainly happen if you eval() user input that isn't properly escaped, but also in code like yours, if the JSON contains user input that isn't properly escaped.  It would look something like this:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var c = JSON.parse('{"type":"ba"}');alert('oh, look, I\'m a nasty script!');//r","data":{"labels":[...]],"datasets":[{},{}, etc]},"options":{"scales":{"yAxes":[{},{}]}}');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, c);
```

In this example the value provided for "type" was: `ba"}');alert('oh, look, I\'m a nasty script!');//r`.  Because it wasn't propery escaped when it was written into the JSON string, the specially constructed value can end the string and execute its own JavaScript.

This has nothing to do with JSON parsing.  You always have to make sure that any user-provided data is properly escaped when you write it onto the page.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to adjust the json if it wasn't built from user input? In this case it's built on the server from the result of a database query

Comment: You should just always apply appropriate escaping when you write text/data onto the page.  Even if the DB data is not malicious, it can still cause bugs if it's not properly escaped.  And do you really know it's not malicious?  All of that DB data came from somewhere -- users filling in forms, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally, I imagine it would be possible to manipulate javascript strings in a "man-in-the-middle" attack? Seems like it would be if HTTPS isn't used

Comment: If you can arrange a MITM attack, you can just put whatever scripts you want on the page and don't have to worry about messing with strings.